# Global expression of 1-forms on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

**Question:** Any 1-form can be expressed as a finite sum $\displaystyle \sum_{i} f_i dg_i$ for some smooth functions $f_i$ and $g_i$.

**My attempt:**

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth real manifold. Let $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i \in I}$ be an atlas for $M$. Let $\{\psi_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$. Let $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ be a $1$-form on $M$. Then, on $U_i$, $\omega$ can be expressed as $$\omega_i=\displaystyle \sum_{j}X^j dx_{i}^j,$$ where $\{X^j\}_{j=1}^n$ are smooth functions and $\{x_{i}^j\}_{j=1}^n$ are local coordinates on $U_i$. Now, globally, we can write $$\omega=\displaystyle \sum_{i} \psi_i \omega_i.$$

Then we have, $$\omega=\displaystyle \sum_{i}\left(\displaystyle \sum_{j}\psi_i X^j\right)dx_{i}^j.$$ Rewrite it as $$\omega=\displaystyle \sum_{i}\left(\displaystyle \sum_{j}\psi_i X^j\right)\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i}\psi_i dx_{i}^j\right).$$

Let $f_i=\displaystyle \sum_{j}\psi_i X^j$. If we have $dg_i=\displaystyle \sum_{i}\psi_i dx_{i}^j$, then we are done. So, we want to find such $g_i$.

I am not able to proceed further. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is $M$ assumed compact?

Comment: @Blazej I'm sorry I don't know. It was not stated in the problem. I think one has to use local finiteness of partitions of unity to conclude this?

Comment: I think your statement is true for compact manifolds. In the general case it is certainly true that one can decompose $\omega=\sum_i f_i dg_i$ in such a way that any point of $M$ has a neighbourhood in which only finitely many terms are nonzero.

Comment: @Blazej I see. Yes, I meant that way only. Locally finite. Can you give me a direction on how to go about proving this, though?

Comment: @Blazej Or if you can provide me with a reference, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that $M$ is compact. Take a local coordinate patch $U$ with coordinates $x^i$ taking values in unit ball. Let $V \subset U$ be the set of points with coordinates such that $\sum_i (x^i)^2 < \frac{1}{2}$. We can find functions $y^i$ which are equal to $x^i$ on $V$ and can be extended to whole $M$ (we can for example assume that they vanish for $\sum_i (x^i)^2 > \frac{3}{4}$). Thus $y^i$ are globally smooth and have the property that at every point of $V$ differential forms $dy^1,...,dy^n$ span the cotangent space. Now any point $p$ of $M$ has a neighbourhood $V_p$ which admits functions $y^i_p$ as above. By compactness, we can find $p_1,...,p_m$ such that $V_{p_1},...,V_{p_m}$ cover $M$. Then all $\{ y_{p_1}^1,...,y_{p_1}^n, ..., y_{p_m}^1,...,y_{p_m}^n \}$ are smooth functions defined on whole $M$. We will take them as our $g_i$. Clearly at every point of $M$ we have that $dg_i$ span the cotangent space. From here it should be easy to finish the proof using partitions of unity.

In the non-compact case I doubt you can always find a finite family of $f_i, g_i$ which works, but I'm pretty sure you can find one such that any point has a neighbourhood in which only finitely many $f_i$ and $g_i$ are nonzero. I will leave the exercise to you; I think you can proceed as I did but invoking paracompactness (instead of compactness) to construct the $g_i$. I have not worked out the details though.

Comment: So are your $y_p^i$ just the $\psi_\alpha x_\alpha^i$ for some $\alpha$? (I find the OP's notation very suboptimal. I would use clearly different indices for the open covering and keep $i$ for the coordinates.)

Comment: The definition I presented is slightly different but the same in spirit. It is not immediately obvious to me that for $g_{\alpha}^i=\psi_{\alpha} x_{\alpha}^i$ it is true that $dg_{\alpha}^i$ span all cotangent spaces, although I do believe that this can be made to work with some care.

Comment: @TedShifrin I completely agree about the sub-optimal notation; I think I ended up getting confused myself. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @Blazej Thanks, I think I see it now! We can essentially use bump functions to smooth out our locally defined functions and work with them. Thanks again!